# Windows Installer XML(WIX) removing files after i uninstall a patch and install it again

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.7

I have an Installer Built using Wix Toolset. I have Created a small Framework that generates patch by using pyro tool, I donot want my Installer to Delete Files on Un-install so i marked all Components as Permanent="yes" property. I created a patch that Removes a file by Marking the Component condition as Permanent="no" and by Condition as FALSE FALSE please find the code below

FALSE

When I install the Patch its not Removing the above file, but if i Uninstall the above patch and install it again its removing the file and working as Expected..Is it Removing the Permanent=yes attribute on First Install and so am able to remove the file on next Install?

Comment: <Component Transitive="yes" Permanent="no" Id="cmpA743661185FC4106BE0A6CE532B30F98" Guid="FD035B1A-78F0-46BC-9A96-88B78DCF33E7" >
                        <File Id="fil589D45BCBC37426EDEEAA1BDC62C4493" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebSitepublishDir)\Lw.WebServices\bin\Lw.System.dll" />
                        <Wix:Condition xmlns:Wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">FALSE</Wix:Condition>
                    </Component>

Comment: Please find my code above